# Parsing field values using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

I am using 10.0 ArcView and am trying to get the "R" in R12345678910 to drop.

The numbers are in a column in the attribute table and i've always used VB scripting.

I was using Field Calculator.

Comment: Where is this R12345678910 at? A field value in an attribute table? In the middle of a script? Field Calculator? Do you want a Python only solution? Some more details may yield more answers.

Comment: Do all the values in your field have the same number of characters and/or number values?  Also, do all the values begin with R?

Comment: yes on both.  R3415160838 is an example, same number of characters and the "R" in front of all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 >>>'R12345678910'[1:]
    '12345678910'
```

Appending `[1:]` to a string in python will remove the initial character. Look up slice in the python help.

To use this in the ArcGIS field calculator, you will need to turn on **Python** parsing

for the `unitCode =` enter

```
!your_field_name![1:]
```

Comment: [1: ] did not work - "there was a failure during processing, check the geoprocessing results window for details"

Answer (score 4):

VBScript Example:

```
Right( [FieldName], 11 )
```

This code will take the 11 characters from the right, and anything left of those 11 characters is omitted.

Python Example:

```
!FieldName!.lstrip('R')
```

This code takes a string and removes R from the left/front of it.

Both of these examples should get rid of the R in your strings.

**Edit:** Regan Sarwas' updated answer works great and is actually more versatile because it can handle more cases.